# uiscroll image gallery

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

I am developing an Image Gallery using scrollview. I want to know can I set the thumbnails on scroll view. I mean I want only 4 thumbnails per row. the 5th one comes in second row.

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code it adds image to scrollview:

```
for (int i=0; i<rand; i++)
    {

        galleryButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
        galleryButton.tag = i;



        if (count ==3) {
            y=30;
            x+=105;

            count=0;
        }

        galleryButton.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, 85, 85);//x=0
        [galleryButton addTarget:self action:@selector(viewButtonPushed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


        y+=90;
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imageArray objectAtIndex:i]];

        NSLog(@"------%@",[imageArray objectAtIndex:i]);

        UIImageView *btnImg = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,97,85)];        
        [btnImg setImage:image];
        count++;


        [galleryButton addSubview:btnImg];
        [imageScroll addSubview:galleryButton];



    }
}
```

Inside viewdidload use the code to set scrollview attribute:

```
[imageScroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(1920,282)];
imageScroll.pagingEnabled =NO; 
[imageScroll setScrollEnabled:YES];
imageScroll.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator=NO;
[imageScroll setCanCancelContentTouches:NO];
imageScroll.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Comment: It will add a huge amount of leaks too.

Comment: how can I know about memory leaks ?

Answer (score 1):

UIScrollView is basically a UIView, so anything that can be done with UIView can be done in scrollView.

as far as I understand, you want your thumbanails to be like this

1 2 3 4

5 6 7 8

which won't be a problem

if you want four thumbnails on one page and other four in other page scroll, again that is also possible.